# Why $\omega +\omega^2 +1 = 0$

Tags: complex-numbers

the title says it all
my teacher just told me to use this formula to solve omega equations without telling me why I asked him about it and he said I won't get it and it was too hard for my age I love math and I want to know why someone can explain in a simplified way and many thanks and love in advance
*EDIT*
I searched In my math book and the value of omega is $-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\sqrt 3}{2}i$

Comment: What is $\omega$? What is an omega equation? Also, please put the question in the main body not just the title, and be more specific.

Comment: Well... have you at least followed your teacher's instruction or are you waiting for one of us to do it?

Comment: @H.sapiensrex what do you mean? I'm asking why omega + omega^2 +1 equals 0 how come it equals zero I'm just curious

Comment: @Sh3ewit $\omega^2+\omega+1=0$ is a quadratic equation. Solve it for $\omega$ and compare the result to whatever other definition for $\omega$ you know, which is missing from your question.

Comment: @Sh3ewit Do you know that $\frac{{x^3  - 1}}{{x - 1}} = x^2  + x + 1$ if $x\ne 1$?

Comment: @Gary im sorry its my first question in here I was just curious how come the equation equals zero and thank you

Comment: @Sh3ewit I am asking you again, what is $\omega$? If $\omega =2$, say, it does not equal to $0$.

Comment: The problem is that nobody here knows what $\omega$ is. Omega equations aren't a standard name for anything. I sympathise with your curiosity, but you're going to need to be more specific if you want someone to understand what you're talking about.

Comment: @Sh3ewit uh... because it does? That's like asking "why does $x-1 = 0$"? It's simply something we define to be true. Whether or not there _is_ such an $\omega$ or $x$ is a completely different question.

Comment: I'm guessing this is about adding and multiplying numbers of the form $a + b\omega$. If so, $\omega^2  +\omega + 1=0$ is something being assumed to be true about $\omega$. Much like how it is assumed that $i^2 + 1 = 0$ in the complex numbers.

Comment: @Gary i edited the post and added omega value

Comment: I guess the question would be : If $\omega^3=1$ with $\omega≠1$, shows that $\omega^2+\omega+1=0$

Comment: @Sh3ewit "*the value of omega is $-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\sqrt 3}{2}i$*" $\;$ So now that you posted what $\omega$ is, have you tried to calculate $\omega^2+\omega+1$ and see what you get?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @lonestudent I think so too; hence my original comment to Sh3ewit: "have you done it yet?"

Comment: @Gary i calculated it and got 1 - 1/2 +sqrt3/2i -1/2-sqrt3/2 which equals zero oh my got im so sorry for wasting your time I didnt know it will be that easy my teacher told me its something hard and out of my league I got curious and excited to know why thank you guys all of you and sorry for wasting your time

Comment: You can just apply the quadratic formula to your title equation to get $\omega = \frac{-1 \pm i\sqrt{3}}{2}$.  If there's another context in which $\omega$ is defined, or considered "special", please edit your question to include it.

Comment: Are the long sentences in the question and your comments a rap?

Comment: Well, follow this standard way . $-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\sqrt 3}{2}i=x\implies \left(x+\frac 12\right)^2=-\frac 34\implies x^2+x+1=0.$ This shows, that $\omega^2+\omega +1=0$

Comment: Learn to punctuate a sentence.

Comment: Please reopen this question now

Comment: @Laska Please also add a rationale for your request. Alternatively you may try to improve the post first. There's also a [reopen queue](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/34447/89922) and chat in meta.

Answer (score 4):

The equation $z^3 = 1$ has $3$ solutions, one real and two complex.

If we subtract $1$ from both sides and factor:

$$(z^3 - 1) = 0\implies (z-1)(z^2+z+1) = 0$$

$\omega$ and $\bar \omega = \omega^2$ are the complex solutions.

Comment: This question seems not to meet the standards for the site. Instead of answering it, why not look for a good duplicate target, or help the user by posting comments suggesting improvements? Please also read the [meta announcement](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards) regarding quality standards.

Comment: A kid has a shitty teacher who won't derive the source of the formulae that he teaches his students and you give me grief for trying to explain it?  The looks like an honest question and not some attemt to get the community to do homework.

Comment: Depending on the level of maths being taught and the teacher's own skill, the teacher may not have been _able_ to derive it. Given that OP's textbook includes the value of $\omega$, it probably also includes the derivation. If it _doesn't_ then I can't imagine OP is expected to know the derivation anyway, meaning that this probably really is just a plug-and-chug exercise in verification

Comment: thanks bro after trying to solve (z^3-1)=0 I used the quadratic formula to solve (z−1)(z^2+z+1)=0
and got omega value
ω = −1/2+3√2i

Answer (score 0):

sorry for wasting everyone's time in the comments I just solved omega +omega^2 +1 = 0 and started with LHS and put omega value which is −1/2+3√2i and got 1 - 1/2 +sqrt3/2i -1/2-sqrt3/2 which equals zero I thought it would be too difficult as my teacher described it but it turned out easy thanks to anyone that commented/answered

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Here is some life advice: taking the time to write with a degree of formality (for example, making use of capital letters and appropriate punctuation) is a good way to signal to your interlocutors that you take them seriously, have a degree of respect for them, and would like them to think well of you.  Not doing these things, on the other hand, gives the opposite impression.

Comment: Along those lines, [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference/5023#5023) is a MathJax tutorial